ADS-L Protocol implementation
I am trying to implement the ADS-L protocol in my application, but I did not fully understand it yet.
Data link layer (page 13):

Why CRC is at offset (Packet Length +1)Bytes if the CRC is included in the "Packet Length" of the first byte?

Network layer (page 16).

In the bullet points it is written that the network layer also contains a payload lenght indicator but the table below does not show any indicator.
Is the "(Packet Length - 3) * 8" the same length then in the table of the data link layer?

My interpretation would look like this:

What is my fault that the offsets do not match for me. Do I use the correct specification because on some pages issue 1 and on some pages issue 4 is written.

The protocol gets updated, it contained minor issues and in a future version they are fixed.
